# Can't send data throught POST method in PHP

Tags: php, post, methods

GET is working but POST doesn't work. Error_log is empty. When I run this code directly to write post_error.

I added this code and wrote this error in the log file.

```
error_log(print_r($_POST,true));
```

> [Thu Oct 04 12:17:35.610967 2018] [fcgid:warn] [pid 16802] [client 162.158.90.26:54114] mod_fcgid: stderr: Array
>
> [Thu Oct 04 12:17:35.611010 2018] [fcgid:warn] [pid 16802] [client 162.158.90.26:54114] mod_fcgid: stderr: (
>
> [Thu Oct 04 12:17:35.611014 2018] [fcgid:warn] [pid 16802] [client 162.158.90.26:54114] mod_fcgid: stderr: )

```
<?php
include('mobiItıraf_dbConfig.php');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){   
    if(isset($_POST['key']) and isset($_POST['nick']) and isset($_POST['pass']) and isset($_POST['pass_saver'])){
        $key = $_POST['key'];
        $user_nick = $_POST['nick'];
        $user_pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $pass_sever = $_POST['pass_saver'];         
        if($key == "1"){
            $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO mobiItiraf_users SET user_nick = ?, user_pass = ?, pass_sever = ?");
            $insert = $query->execute(array($user_nick,$user_pass,$pass_sever));
            if($insert){
                echo "in";
            }else{
                echo "not in";
            }
        }else{
            echo "key error";
        }
    }else{
        echo "isset error";
    }
}else{
    echo "post_error";
}
```

?>

Comment: Are you doing a POST request? Is $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] really set to 'POST' in your request?

This seems to be an http form handler, possibly for a login, so how do that script look?

Comment: FYI, `isset()` can receive multiple values at once.  You're not really saving raw passwords to the database, right?  ...right?

Comment: @Virre I just talked to my server provider and say that POST is turned off, but I've been using this server for 3 months and it's been like this for the last 2 days. I wonder if this may be due to this? Also the GET method is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` may contain POST for HTTP GET requests on some PHP Apache2 servers.

First solution is to use `===` instead of `==` because `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` can return 0 value or a conflict with upper and lower case

```
if(strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 'POST')
```

or a simple way is to use a short way using just

```
if ($_POST)
```

@edit: If this doesnt work can you please do a var_dump of the $_POST

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just saw that our edits did conflict, mea culpa for that!

Comment: np @maio290 :) Mehmet please do a var_dump($_POST) to see what are you posting please.

Comment: @Sigma var_dump($_POST); is empty

Comment: At this point please add the html code where you are submitting the values, a form or whatever you are using to see if there is any error there.